# How can make a balanced equipment deck with seasons 1 and 2, and TCM?

Tags: zombicide

When playing with both season 1 and 2, and TCM, what is the best way to build the equipment deck so it is not unbalanced? It seems like the likelihood of drawing a three damage weapon is quite low with all the cards together.

Comment: Why? It's been a while, but I don't seem to remember a reason to mix S1 and S2 together. Just use one of them.

Comment: @ikegami Some weapons are exclusive to each such as pans, night sticks and the concrete saw to name a few

Comment: There are no pans or nightsticks in the deck. Those are starting equipment. My question stands.

Comment: @ikegami There are more than three pans in the deck. One might want the variety of various weapons such as the nightsticks or riot shields as mentioned earlier. A better way to look at the question would be if the decks are already combined how should they be broken down?

Comment: Not when I play. They're just starting equipment as far as I'm concerned. The nightsticks replace the pans, and it would be silly to play with both. So, that leaves you wanting to use riot shields and a concrete saw. That's not a reason to mix the two decks. Either use the deck that has them, or adds those to the other deck.

Comment: Your interpretation of the rules doesn't really answer my question nor does it make sense to say using both would be silly because that's just an opinion

Comment: Then why are thier more than three?

Comment: I counted there are 8 pans. There would be no reason to include them if you war only going to use three.

Comment: There are three pans in S1, allowing for 6-player games. 4 were added in TCM allowing for 10-player games. The rules literally say "Put aside the [...] Pan [...] cards."

Comment: That makes more sense thank you for explaining that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *It seems like the likelihood of drawing a three damage weapon is quite low with all the cards together.*

S1 alone is the worst. S1+S2 is about the same as just S2. Adding TCM greatly improves the odds.

- S1: 2/52 = 3.8% (2 sets of Molotov ingredients)
- S2: 3/71 = 4.2% (2 sets of Molotov ingredients, Concrete Saw)
- S1+S2: 5/123 = 4.1%
- S1+TCM* = 5:/69 = 7.2% (2 sets of .44 Magnum + Hollow-Point Rounds, Flamethrower)
- S2+TCM* = 6/88 = 6.9%
- S1+S2+TCM* = 8/140 = 5.7%

TCM* = TCM excluding Ultrareds.

> *A better way to look at the question would be if the decks are already combined how should they be broken down?*

- S1 - 62 equipment cards

  - 52-card deck:

    - 4x Aaahh!
    - 3x Bag of Rice
    - 2x Baseball Bat
    - 3x Canned Food
    - 2x Chainsaw
    - 1x Crowbar
    - 1x Fire Axe
    - 2x Flashlight
    - 2x Gasoline
    - 2x Glass Bottles
    - 1x Goalie Mask
    - 2x Katana
    - 4x Machete
    - 2x Pistol
    - 3x Plenty of Ammo (bullets)
    - 3x Plenty of Ammo (shells)
    - 2x Rifle
    - 2x Scope
    - 4x Sawed Off
    - 2x Shotgun
    - 2x Sub MG
    - 3x Water
  - Set aside:

    - 1x Crowbar
    - 1x Evil Twins
    - 1x Fire Axe
    - 1x Ma's Shotgun
    - 2x Molotov
    - 3x Pan
    - 1x Pistol
- TCM - 23 equipment cards (itemized in the rulebook)

  - 17 cards to add to deck:

    - 2x .44 Magnum
    - 2x Assault Rifle
    - 2x Cookies
    - 2x Gas Mask
    - 1x Flamethrower
    - 2x Hollow-Point Rounds
    - 4x Laser Pointer
    - 2x Spare Change
  - 6 Ultrared cards to add to deck:

    - 1x 911 Special
    - 1x Betty
    - 1x Doug's Dream
    - 1x Jack & Jill
    - 1x Ned's Atomic Flashlight
    - 1x Sweet Sisters
  - Set aside:

    - 1x Pa's Gun
    - 4x Pan
- S2:PO - 83 equipment cards (itemized in the rulebook)

  - 71-card deck:

    - 2x Automatic Shotgun
    - 4x Aaahh!
    - 3x Bag of Rice
    - 2x Baseball Bat
    - 3x Canned Food
    - 2x Chainsaw
    - 3x Claw Hammer
    - 1x Concrete Saw
    - 1x Fire Axe
    - 2x Flashlight
    - 2x Gasoline
    - 2x Glass Bottles
    - 4x Hatchet
    - 2x Katana
    - 4x Kukri
    - 2x Meat Cleaver
    - 2x Nails
    - 5x Pistol
    - 3x Plenty of Ammo (bullets)
    - 3x Plenty of Ammo (shells)
    - 2x Rifle
    - 2x Riot Shield
    - 4x Sawed Off
    - 2x Scope
    - 2x Shotgun
    - 2x Sub MG
    - 2x Wakizachi
    - 3x Water
  - Set aside:

    - 2x Gunblade
    - 2x Nailbat
    - 3x Nightstick
    - 2x Molotov
    - 1x Claw Hammer
    - 1x Fire Axe
    - 1x Pistol

Comment: Found out that all of Chainsaws were in my S1 pile, and a set of S1 starter weapons (Fireaxe, Crowbar and Pistol) were in S2 pile. So this was useful :)